# Process Communication from C#/VB.net/VC++ application to Java application

Tags: c#

Is process communication possible from C#/VB.net/VC++ application to Java application?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please define *communicate*. It is a such a broad question that cannot be answered without giving more details.

Answer (score 1):

You mean over a network? Sure, google for Sockets, Web Services, Messaging to get you started.

The best option will depend on what you want to do and your constraints - for a more specific answer, you'll need to provide more specific details (as the comment on your question says)